# Is it possible to directly tweet with out tweet dialog via Twitter native app

Tags: android, twitter

Is it possible to directly tweet via Twitter app with out open Twitter app and press tweet button in  tweet dialog ?

this is my tweet code its work fine

but i want to skip this step

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setClassName("com.twitter.android", "com.twitter.android.PostActivity");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri);      
startActivity(intent);
```

[image]

i don't want to use external library